# Using crunch with word as pattern

Tags: shell, passwords

I've just started using crunch and I was wondering how to generate a wordlist using "entire words as charset".
For example, I would like to generate all possible words composed by `mom` `dad` & `1990`
The result should be something like that (with all possibilities) :

```
mom
dad
1990
mommom
momdad
mom1990
dadmom
...
mommommom
mommomdad
momdadmom
momdaddad
momdad1990
mom1990mom
...
```

I tried : `crunch 5 9 'mom' 'dad' '1990'`but it didn't work for sure

Answer (score -1):

good question !!! you may want to look at the manual of crunch type man crunch in a terminal you will find out the option -p which means factorial

-p charset OR -p word1 word2 ...
              Tells   crunch   to  generate  words  that  don't  have  repeating  characters.   By  default  crunch  will  generate  a  wordlist  size  of
              #of_chars_in_charset ^ max_length.  This option will instead generate #of_chars_in_charset!.  The ! stands for factorial.  For  example  say
              the  charset is abc and max length is 4..  Crunch will by default generate 3^4 = 81 words.  This option will instead generate 3! = 3x2x1 = 6
              words (abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba).  THIS MUST BE THE LAST OPTION!  This option CANNOT be used with -s and it ignores min and  max  length
              however you must still specify two numbers

the only drawback for that you will not get these in your wordlist 
"mom
dad
1990
mommom
momdad"
so you can use the option -d take that command for example 
crunch 2 2 0123456789 -t dd   -o /root/Desktop/abc.txt -p mom dad 1990

you will get here every possible combination composed of 2 words but I have to tell you that wont solve the problem because if you used only one d or increased another word after -p you will get repetitions up to the factorial result for example if you put 6 words the generated list will contain 6! that means 6*5*4*3*2*1 and so on

So I recommend using concatenation in excel eg fx=A1&B2